# gcp container cluster initialization failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

```
 ~ gcloud container clusters create example-cluster
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, 
message=Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.zones.get' permission 
for 'projects/saleop-166407/zones/asia-northeast1-a'
```

This is the shell script I used to start a container cluster.
I failed with web console(using UI), gcloud sdk cli and google cloud shell.
It is saying something about permission, but I couldn't find any change I made.

So I created a new project and did the same thing then It worked. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change the roles of your `Compute Engine default service account` in `Console --> IAM/Admin --> IAM` section, or for other accounts? It looks like your Compute account cannot use the compute API.
[image]

Make sure your Compute Engine default service account has "Editor" role on your project.

That's the only explanation I can think of, because when you create a new project, that project gets a brand new Compute Engine service account with correct permissions.

Comment: It was set to editor already. I disabled and re-enabled compute engine api and solved the problem.